# Input cell data from Excel into Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm looking to make an automated email script using vba to read from an Excel spreadsheet; the email address and dates (that sort of thing) then place them into the correct fields to send

It would be preferable if it could also finish the line of the spreadsheet and start a new one with a new email

I can currently make an email with vba but that's about it and manually dictate the fields within the script but that's about it. Any help on how to input cell data automatically would be much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Edit 1:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Send_email()

Dim Line As Long
Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application

    For Line = 2 To 3
        Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        With OutlookMail
            .To = Range("A" & Line).Value
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "OVERDUE DOCUMENTATION - " & Range("C" & Line).Value & " " & Range("B" & Line).Value & " - " & Range("D" & Line).Value

            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            .Display
            .HTMLBody = "Dear " & Range("F" & Line).Value & "," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "The documentation for " & Range("C" & Line).Value & " " & Range("B" & Line).Value & "'s appointment with Dr " & Range("E" & Line).Value & " on " & Range("D" & Line).Value & " is now overdue." & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Please send through the documentation immediately or the doctor may cancel this appointment due to insufficient time too view the documents prior to the appointment." & "<br>" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Regards," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Documents Team" & .HTMLBody
          End With
    Next Line

End Sub
```

This seems to be the solve in case anyone has the same issue.
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code for what you've attempted so far?

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, please be sure to upvote / accept an answer to close the post and to show others the solution if they have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is more specific when defining the cells, which worked during my testing.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Send_email()

    Dim Line As Long
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For Line = 2 To 3
        Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        With OutlookMail
            .To = ws.Range("A" & Line).Value
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "OVERDUE DOCUMENTATION - " & ws.Range("C" & Line).Value & " " & ws.Range("B" & Line).Value & " - " & ws.Range("D" & Line).Value

            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            .Display
            .HTMLBody = "Dear " & ws.Range("F" & Line).Value & "," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "The documentation for " & ws.Range("C" & Line).Value & " " & ws.Range("B" & Line).Value & "'s appointment with Dr " & ws.Range("E" & Line).Value & " on " & ws.Range("D" & Line).Value & " is now overdue." & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Please send through the documentation immediately or the doctor may cancel this appointment due to insufficient time too view the documents prior to the appointment." & "<br>" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Regards," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Documents Team" & .HTMLBody
          End With
    Next Line

End Sub
```